# Replacing characters in a vector in R studio: for-loops, gsubs?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, replace, gsub

I have a vector, which has roughly 8000 characters. The values are for body mass index and I need to change them to **1** for `normal`, **2** for `overweight` and **3** for `obese`, based on the following:

```
<=24.9 Normal,   
25.0—29.9 Overweight,  
30.0+ = Obese.
```

What would be the quickest way of going about this?
I have looked into for-loops and gsub but neither seem to get work quite right. 
Also, the vector has a few NA values, which I need to remain as NA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your BMI values are numeric you can use `cut` to categorise (& label these)

```
# Data - with a few missing values
set.seed(1)
bmi <- rnorm(100,40,10)
bmi[c(2,10,20)] <- NA

# Categorise
bmi.cat <- cut(bmi , breaks=c(0 , 25 , 30, max(bmi , na.rm=TRUE)) , 
           labels = c("nornal" , "over", "obese"), 
           right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)

table(bmi.cat , exclude=NULL) # 3 values still missing

 # check range of BMI within categories
 by(bmi , bmi.cat , range , na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An simple approach:

```
myvec[myvec <= 24.9] <- 1
myvec[myvec > 30] <- 3
myvec[myvec > 3] <- 2
```